# Assertion error in animation library: Number of matrices registered is equal to the max number set at creation time

Tags: animation, directx, sample, demo

When I replace the `tiny_anim.x` animation file with another one in the DirectX multianimation demo I get the following error:

```
Assertion failure! (s:\gfx_sdknovember08\windows\directx\dxg\d3d11\d3dx9\anim\loadxh.cpp 1392): D3DXFrameNumNamedMatrices(pframeRoot) == plc->cNamedMatrices
D3DX: ID3DXAnimationController::RegisterAnimationOutput: Number of matrices registered is equal to the max number set at creation time.
```

This is only with some exported models and not with all.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the November 2008 SDK?  Try using the March 2009 SDK (or August 2009 SDK if its out by the time you read this).